# Is there a less recursive feeling way of formatting numbers?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there a C# equivalent of C++'s stream manipulators?
Eg

```
int decimalPlaces = 2;
double pi = 3.14159;
cout.precision(decimalPlaces);
cout << pi;
```

It feels weird having to format a number to a string in order to format a number to a string.
Eg

```
int decimalPlaces = 2;
double pi = 3.14159;
string format = "N" + decimalPlaces.ToString();
pi.ToString(format);
```

It that just how it's done in C#, or did I miss something?

Comment: You can write the third line as `string format = "N" + decimalPlaces;` (omit the method call) as it's cleaner, and `.ToString()` is implied.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah, I got that, but I left it in since it served to emphasize my point about the recursive feeling of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would shrink it slightly:

```
int decimalPlaces = 2;
double pi = 3.14159;
pi.ToString("N" + decimalPlaces);
```

Also, you don't *have* to format the number before printing it. The printing facilities will accept formatting constructs too.

Comment: But the formatting construct are still strings, right? So I'm still calling decimalPlaces.ToString(), just somewhere else.

Comment: C# automatically calls `ToString()` when doing string concatenation. I don't know of any easy way to avoid that.

Comment: So basically, no. I was not expecting that. Thanks.